# Not getting correct x axis value on onclick event for chartDiv in AmChart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amcharts

I am using Amchart for data representation for Speed v/s time/latlong. I need x-axis value on click event on the chart div. I have tried it with lots efforts but failed to get the correct x-axis value on click on the chart.

I am getting the amchart x-axis value using category axis as below:

```
document.getElementById('chartdiv').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
var ss = chart.categoryAxis.xToIndex(e.x);
var vall = chart.categoryAxis.data[ss].category;
alert(vall);
 });
```

Mismatch the x-axis-value and alert value onclick the chart as:

[image]

My Efforts as [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jayantilal/5r6m6y7y/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue with amchart support team help that my mistake to pass index of category axis instead of its value as

var ss = chart.categoryAxis.index;

Thanks all for support.

Answer (score 0):

following is the proper way to listen to the clickItem event on axes

```
chart.addListener("rendered", function(e) {
    e.chart.categoryAxis.addListener("clickItem",function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#clickItem

Comment: The click event is not issue. The x-axis value on click event is not correct.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/5r6m6y7y/3/ the clickItem is for the categoryAxis label, in this case you need to grab the current index of the cursor to get the right value.

Answer (score 0):

var ss = chart.categoryAxis.index;